# Best way to send mail from different from adresses

Tags: php, email, smtp

I've read multiple threads over internet to try finding the best possible soulution and would gladly hear what you think.

I work with a bussiness platform and our customers(users), need to send mail as their company.
Example:

> - From: info@company.com
> - From: news@anotherCompany.com

1)
We are currently using the inbuild php **mail()** function with **included headers** and be able to set "from" domain as we want. This works kinda okay but we are recently starting to get matched as SPAM more and more from some email domains like hotmail and we are haveing a hard time finding soultions.

2)
We have thought of using SMTP server

But...

> - You are bound to use the same from-domain as username in many cases.
>
> Therefor we thought we might use one main SMTP domain and then use the "reply to". But...
>
> - The **Reply-to** does not work in some mailprograms, ex: windows 10 mail. It still selects the main domain sender email.
>
> It's also a huge project to ask our clients to provide (if they even have) their own SMTP login information. As some of them even don't know if they run MAC or Windows.

3) Third party API's for example https://postmarkapp.com/ etc.
Will they fit the role?

Are there any other soulutions that I've missed to work around this?

**And what would you chose to go with?**

Is php mail with "correct" headers enought? Should we gather SMTP login information from our customers as primary and use PHP mail as fallback?

Answer (score -1):

Sending email hasn't been much fun lately. In the past using `mail()` in PHP was perfectly adequate, but it is no longer.

Just using any SMTP server doesn't solve the problem either. Your server has to comply with a lot of rules created by Google, Microsoft and Yahoo to combat spam.

Here are some links (ignore talk about bulk mail, this does apply to all senders):

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en

https://mail.live.com/mail/policies.aspx

https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN3435.html

These might not be the best links, but you get the idea.

Setting up your own SMTP server is a nightmare. You have to make it your day job for a month.

I was lucky in that my hosting provider provides a good SMTP server which I can use for all my domains. It will also allow me to send mail from all the email addresses I've set up for each domain. Ask your hosting provider if they do something similar. This is the best solution, by far.

Alternatively you can rent access to a SMTP server with these services attached.

Without wanting to sound like an advert: I have used https://sendgrid.com/marketing/smtp-server and found it to be very good. But there are loads of alternatives. (Please note that this last solution only replaces the PHP `mail()` function, not general mailing by your customers from their email clients!)

Comment: Thank you for taking time answearing, I will have a read on all your links.
I also have read about third party API like you mention, maybe it is the only way to go. But then it feels like it really need to be able to handle the amount. Our website are hosted on own dedicated servers, and we can have up to 5000+ email adresses...

Comment: Just scan the links... see all the conditions: headers, reverse DNS, SPF, DKIM, DMARC, etc, etc... then try to find a good SMTP hoster. :-) You only have to be worried about the number of domains.